# Informix - Insert result of dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1') into a table

Tags: sql, informix

I want to insert multiple records into a table with a SERIAL column using a single statement if possible.

I also need to know what values were generated by the inserts. My approach has been to try and store the result of dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1') within a temporary table after each insert and then read the table at the end.

My code goes something like this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE Ids1410363201 (ID INT);

INSERT INTO tableA (title) VALUES ('Test1');

INSERT INTO Ids1410363201 (ID)
VALUES (dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1'));

INSERT INTO tableA (title) VALUES ('Test2');

INSERT INTO Ids1410363201 (ID)
VALUES (dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1')); 

INSERT INTO tableA (title) VALUES ('Test3');

INSERT INTO Ids1410363201 (ID)
VALUES (dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1')); 

select ID
from Ids1410363201
```

The schema of the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (ID SERIAL, title VARCHAR(50))
```

However, 0 is being inserted into the temp table rather than the value of the SERIAL column. So the final select returns:

```
ID
--
0
0
0
```

Is their any way to get the actual SERIAL numbers into the temp table? Or is there a different approach I could employ?

I'm using Informix v12.1

**EDIT**

Specifically, I'm targeting Informix v12.10.FC9WE. I'm running on a Windows 7 machine using IBM's 64bit Informix ODBC driver (v3.70.TC7). I've tried two clients: Database.net and a generic ODBC client simply called "Query Tool".

Comment: Using Informix 12.10.FC8DE and the `dbaccess` client I am getting the serial values that you expected in the temp table. Which specific Informix version are you using? And which client?

Comment: The code you show works for me on a Mac using my SQLCMD program against Informix 12.10.FC6.  I agree with @LuísMarques: we're going to need more information about what you're using to see the problem.  What do you get from creating a script and running it with DB-Access?  That worked for me too.

Comment: I've edited the question and added further information. I will try db-acesss

Comment: I've jut tried it using the SQuirell client (which uses a JDBC driver) and it works. I'm thinking it may be a driver issue.